# Make some responses in Google Forms private

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a Google form as a questionnaire and would like to allow people to see some parts of the responses but not others. I am not a programmer, so not really into using scripts to sort them into two spreadsheets.

Is there an easy way of doing this? It would be quite helpful if there was a setting on each question to indicate if it is a private or public response, but this does not look like being there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sharing the responses sheet use a IMPORTRANGE and FILTER or QUERY to pass to a second spreadsheet only the "public" responses share that spreadsheet with them.

The formula will look like the following, assuming the in Column C will include "Public" for the public responses.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key,reference),"Select * Where Col3 = "Public")
```